# my startup script does not start when I want to

Tags: linux, debian, startup, init, mariadb

So I am having a bash script in `/etc/init.d/` containing this init info:

```
 ### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          minio server
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $mysql $all
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     5
# Default-Stop:      
# Short-Description: Start minio server that were running during shutdown
# Description:       Start minio server that were running during shutdown, wether unexpected or not
### END INIT INFO
```

because this script needs mariadb to run I put the `$mysql` in the Required-Start, even though `$all` should (from my understanding) already asure that mariadb is started, as the header of the `mysql` file looks like this:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          mysql
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Should-Start:      $network $named $time
# Should-Stop:       $network $named $time
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
# Description:       Controls the main MariaDB database server daemon "mysqld"
#                    and its wrapper script "mysqld_safe".
### END INIT INFO
```

so the script is checking whether this deamon is running:

```
for seconds in {1..60}
do
    sleep 1
    find_pid=$(ps 'aux'| grep "sql")
    pid="${find_pid:5:25}"
    stringarray=($pid)
    pid=${stringarray[0]}

    find_pid=$(ps 'aux'| grep "sql")
    pid_two="${find_pid:5:25}"
    stringarray=($pid_two)
    pid_two=${stringarray[0]}

    if [ $pid == $pid_two]; then
        break
    fi
done
if [[ $seconds == 60 ]]; then
    echo "database not started yet" | tee -a /var/www/html/startup.log
fi
```

But for some reason the database is never started when the script is executed.
Somebody got an idea on how to fix that?

EDIT: I have also tried [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/10811/how-to-add-a-script-to-startup-and-shutdown-in-debian) but even after running `update-rc.d YOURAPP defaults` as suggested in the link, the database is not started when the script is run.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving it in `init.d`, try adding the script in `/etc/rc.local`

EG: open /etc/rc.local, then

```
path_to_binary path_to_scipt
```

Comment: Considering [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/10811/how-to-add-a-script-to-startup-and-shutdown-in-debian) I would still have to add the file to `init.d` ,correct?

Comment: Hi, just need to add on `/etc/rc.local`, give it a try.

Comment: even if I´d have to create the folder? I have got the rc folders for the different run levels (so 0-6) and a folder calleds rcS.d/ but no folder called rc.local. I have got debian buster